# Columns too wide in Highcharts with lots of points

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In a Highcharts column chart with a lot of data points, say one per day for a full year the columns are too wide in my opinion. How to give them a width of e.g. 1 pixel? I unsuccessfully tried this:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        pointWidth: 1
    }
},
```

[Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/burktelefon/sesrkzbg/).

Comment: According to the [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.pointWidth) you have it correct.

Comment: Your fiddle looks fine to me.

Comment: So, that's as thin as the columns can be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply get rid of the border by setting `borderWidth` to 0. Take a look at corrected example below.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.borderWidth

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/sLmj0z5z/

Comment: Aha 'borderWidth'! That looks, not perfect, but much better. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have more series data so labes `pointWidth: 1`  is fine otherwise we have to delete series data or use like this

[Highcharts API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.width)

```
chart: {
        zoomType: 'x',
        width:525

    },
```